# MATLAB Autocomplete text at command window

Tags: matlab, autocomplete

Does anyone knows a plugin for Matlab to autocomplete text in the command windows?

I don´t like to press tab because that does not help me enough, for instance if I put before something like

```
>>sprintf('%0.18f %0.18f %0.18\n', [output1; ouput2; output3])
```

and I want to use the same expression if I press tab as much I get to put 'sprintf' but not the rest of the string I used before, '('%0.18f %0.18f %0.18\n', [output1; ouput2; output3])'

I don´t know not the reason that matlab does not include this feature.

I think there should be something much better than just pressing the up arrow key, because imagine that the last 25 entries are different from each other. But it´s possible to make some sets, for instance there are 7 entries that they begin with 'sprintf'. May be you have to pressing up arrow key 18 times to get the entries that begin with 'sprintf'. But you would write 's' and in one time you get the 'sprintf' entries. I think a autocomplete text application would be faster than pressing 18 times the up arrow key.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quoting from the documentation ...

> Instead of retyping the entire line,
>   press the up arrow key.

**EDIT:**
Typing the first letter(s) in your command window before hitting the arrow key will filter commands not starting with an exact match of the given letter(s).

Comment: I think there should be something much better than just pressing the up arrow key, because imagine that the last 25 entries are different from each other. But it´s possible to make some sets, for instance there are 7 entries that they begin with 'sprintf'. May be you have to pressing up arrow key 18 times to get the entries that begin with 'sprintf'. But you would write 's' and in one time you get the 'sprintf' entries. I think a autocomplete text aplication would be faster than pressing 18 times the up arrow key.

Answer (score 4):

It works exactly as you decribed it: start typing first few characters and press the up arrow key.